# How to set '-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.experimental' in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, compiler-warnings, ktor

while trying to build a Kotlin/Ktor application in IntelliJ, multiple warnings of the form

```
Warning:(276, 6) Kotlin: This class can only be used with the compiler argument '-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental'
```

are output.  The warnings refer to

```
@UseExperimental(KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI::class)
```

so I expected to satisfy the warning by setting *Settings -> Build -> Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler -> Additional command line parameters* to **-version -Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental**.  (**-version** was already there).  But the warning is still generated.  How do I satisfy it?  Thanks in expectation.

Comment: You should follow the tip, try to use @UnstableDefault

Answer (score 29):

Are you using Maven or Gradle for your project?  I had the same issue with Gradle, but I was able to remove the warnings by putting the **-Xuse-experimental=kotlin.Experimental** in my **build.gradle** file, inside a **tasks.withType**.

For **KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI** you could try:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xuse-experimental=io.ktor.locations.KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI"]
}
```

Comment: how about if we using a lot of experimental features? e.g: `UnstableDefault`, and `ImplicitSerialization`. Does the argument would look like this? `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xuse-experimental=io.ktor.locations.KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI, UnstableDefault, Implicit, etc"]
`

Comment: Updated my comment above: when using multiple args, you can do so: 


`kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += [
"-Xuse-experimental=io.ktor.locations.KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI", 
"-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.serialization.UnstableDefault",
"-Xuse-experimental=kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitSerialization"]`

Answer (score 24):

In the current Kotlin version (1.5), you can use any experimental library by adding @OptIn annotation

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
```

However, the opt-in mechanism is experimental itself, and to use it you will need to add a compiler argument. The most idiomatic way to do that in Kotlin Multiplatform is:

```
kotlin.sourceSets.all {
    languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
}
```

Comment: `languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation()` has recently been replaced by `languageSettings.optIn()`

Answer (score 7):

In `build.gradle.kts`

##### Mostly on multiplatform projects

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions{
        kotlin.sourceSets.all {
            languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
        }
    }
}
```

##### Single platform

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        // ...
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}
```

Comment: This one is only one valid as of 29.4.2022 with latest versions

Answer (score 4):

Edit for **Graddle 6.5.1** and **Ktor 1.3.2**.
Answer by @jay-janez looks like that:

```
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xuse-experimental=io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to your `app/build.gradle` file and add the below task on the bottom part

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but there has been some changes.

`-Xuse-experimental` has been replaced by `-Xopt-in`. [See the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/opt-in-requirements.html).

Also for Grade Kotlin DSL you can use this syntax:

```
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf(
        "-Xopt-in=io.ktor.util.KtorExperimentalAPI"
    )
}
```

Comment: Getting `Could not get unknown property 'withType' for task set of type`. I guess the place where I'm adding this is wrong or this has changed with the new version of Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You can add -opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn compiler argument in the build

```
  kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
        ]
    }
```