# How does Kotlin's Json.decodeFromString work without a first DeserializationStrategy argument?

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm very new to Kotlin and am curious what magic allows this code to work:

From https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/e2e764a132c8eebd31208120774baf9a71ec23c7/formats/json/commonTest/src/kotlinx/serialization/SerializerForNullableTypeTest.kt

```
@Serializable
data class Box(val s: StringHolder?)

val deserialized = Json.decodeFromString<Box>(string)
```

When the function definition seems to require an initial argument before the encoded JSON string.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/e2e764a132c8eebd31208120774baf9a71ec23c7/formats/json/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/json/Json.kt

```
public final override fun <T> decodeFromString(deserializer: DeserializationStrategy<T>, string: String): T {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method is currently part of an experimental API in [SerialFormat.kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/e2e764a132c8eebd31208120774baf9a71ec23c7/core/commonMain/src/kotlinx/serialization/SerialFormat.kt):

It is an extension function with the following interface:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
public inline fun <reified T> StringFormat.encodeToString(value: T): String
```

You need to [enable experimental APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787542/how-to-set-xuse-experimental-kotlin-experimental-in-intellij) to be able to use it.

Comment: Do you mind providing more details? I added this to project level build.gradle: 
```tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xuse-experimental=org.jetbrains.kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi"]
}``` 
 and added `@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)` to the function calling the API, but it still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Bao  were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 21):

Adding the import below works for me.

```
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString
```

[Kotlin Official Document](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/serialization.html#example-json-serialization)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31298912)

Comment: Thanks JS84.  This answer solved the question for me.  I had a "DeserializationStrategy required" error, and including this import allowed me to send a String, as expected.  I think the included link is also helpful.  Note: I did not need to include any OptIn or Experimental flags.  I assume this is now old stuff.

Answer (score 4):

To use this you need to import `import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString`. But because this is an [experimental API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787542/how-to-set-xuse-experimental-kotlin-experimental-in-intellij), you also need to mark your class or method with `@ExperimentalSerializationApi`. But to enable experimental switches you also need to add an compiler by `languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")`.

#### `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.5.31"
}

kotlin.sourceSets.all {
    languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
}
```

#### `test.kts`

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialFormat
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString

@Serializable
data class Box(val s: String = "")

@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
fun readJson(){
    val deserialized = Json.decodeFromString<Box>("""{"s" : "Hallo"}""")
}
```

Comment: In my case only `kotlinx.serialization.json.Json` and `kotlinx.serialization.decodeFromString` were required. No need to use `@OptIn` or those two other imports. And what comes to plugins part: `plugins { id 'com.android.application';id 'kotlin-android';id 'kotlinx-serialization' apply true }`