# The Suppress("OPT_IN_IS_NOT_ENABLED") doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

After suppressing the OptIn warning, I was expecting it would go away, but it's still popping up after compile, any way to get rid of it?

```
@Suppress("OPT_IN_IS_NOT_ENABLED")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing in the option to the compiler itself? You should be able to do it on your project's gradle file.

Comment: I've tried putting it in command line options but that didn't work, there's probably a way to add it to gradle somehow but I'm not sure how. Do you have a link I could try?

Comment: You should be able to add it to your gradle file. It should be something like:

```
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can search for "set kotlin compiler opt in arguments gradle file"

Comment: Thanks I found the right page by searching for your keyword

Answer (score 2):

According to this question: [How to set Opt in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787542/how-to-set-xuse-experimental-kotlin-experimental-in-intellij) what resolves the problem is adding the following snippet to build.gradle (app)

```
kotlin.sourceSets.all {
    languageSettings.optIn("kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
}
```