# Upgrading Android Grade Plugin from 7.1.3 to 7.2.2 breaks project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm taking care of an Android app, but I have no experience with Android. The app was accepted at the app store, but recently Android 10 and earlier users report problems. They can install the app, but when they want to start it, they see "App not installed".

I'm now trying to update everything within the app, hoping that fixes the issue.

Within the `build.gradle` there is a block "dependencies" with the line

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
```

Upgrading to the [next minor version / highest patch version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
```

When I run `./gradlew bundleRelease`, I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration of project ':app' has not completed yet.
```

Where do I have to look for the issue? Is it maybe even possible to say what a fix would look like?

Is there a **changelog** for `com.android.tools.build:gradle` where I could check what broke with 7.2 / how I can fix it? I could not find it on [the official website](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: I needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/68246952/562769

> `languageSettings.useExperimentalAnnotation()` has recently been replaced by `languageSettings.optIn()`

and update to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'`